# Using cheerio to scrape a page won't work well

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parsing, cheerio

I have a page which looks like this:

```
                           <li title="Sulphurous" class='item q-440-5 q-440-border-5' data-tip="top" >
<a href="/effect/Sulphurous"><div class='item-icon' style='background-image:url(),url(/images/440/particles/64_94x94.png)'></div><div class='tag bottom-right'>avg 207.61</div><div class='tag top-left'>sulphurous</div></a>
<span style='display:none'>Unusual Sulphurous</span></li>



                            <li title="Purple Confetti" class='item q-440-5 q-440-border-5' data-tip="top" >
<a href="/effect/Purple%20Confetti"><div class='item-icon' style='background-image:url(),url(/images/440/particles/7_94x94.png)'></div><div class='tag bottom-right'>avg 57.39</div><div class='tag top-left'>p.fetti</div></a>
<span style='display:none'>Unusual Purple Confetti</span></li>
```

I want to extract `title` and `tag bottom-right`. The result should look like this:

```
name: Unusual Sulphurous
price: avg 207.61

name: Unusual Purple Confetti
price: avg 57.39
```

How do I extract `avg 207.61` and `avg 57.39` using cheerio?

I am only able to parse the title. Here's my script:

```
    $('li').each(function(){
        var name = ($(this).attr('title'));
        var price = ($(this).attr('tag bottom-right')); 

        nameList.push({
                  name: name,
                  price: price,
        });
    });
```

But the price is `undefined`. I tried `tag_bottom-right`, `tag-bottom-right`, `tag.bottom-right` and `.tag.bottom-right` but it still didn't work.

Also tried doing this:

```
    $("tag.bottom-right").each(function() {
        let id = ($(this).data("tag.bottom-right"));
     });
```

But still `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the right css:

```
let prices = $(".tag.bottom-right").map((i, el) => $(el).text())
```

Comment: thanks. so it is not possible to get single price one by one using  `let price = $(` inside of `$('li').each(function(){ ... });` ?

Comment: You can do something inside the each but each doesn't return anything.